# Подскажите библиотеку для визуализации графов

Tags: javascript, jquery, графы, визуализация

Необходимо визуализировать граф. По сути, в данный момент только один вид графа - бинарное дерево. Нашел [сравнение + примеры](http://anvaka.github.io/graph-drawing-libraries/#/all) некоторых библиотек. Поидее, то [что нужно](http://anvaka.github.io/graph-drawing-libraries/performance/?lib=almende%2Fvis&graph=balancedBinTree&n=3) но это только когда глубина 3. При глубине [8 и более](http://anvaka.github.io/graph-drawing-libraries/performance/?lib=almende_vis&graph=balancedBinTree&n=8) начинает уже подлагивать, да и строится некорректно - почему-то одна из веток начинает наезжать на начало графа.

Есть другая библиотека, с ней не лагает даже при [глубине 10](http://anvaka.github.io/graph-drawing-libraries/performance/?lib=anvaka%2FVivaGraphJS&graph=balancedBinTree&n=10), поэтому думаю что она предпочтительна. Но дерево опять же строится с пересечением веток. Есть предположение что это из-за анимации и после N времени он выровняется (тихо, но верно оно к этому идет), но нужно чтоб оно изначально построилось корректно, а уже потом пусть делает что хочет. Судя по документации это все настраивается, но пока еще разбираюсь. Но может кто уже сталкивался с этим и может что подсказать.

Или может кто-нибудь может подсказать библиотеку для этого, навряд ли здесь представлены все. На данный момент поидее необходимо от него

- Быть масштабируемым (глубина 8+ это уже огромное дерево)
- Иметь возможность нажать на элемент (хотелось бы добавить всплывашку)

Comment: Если есть время, можете разобраться в [d3](https://d3js.org/). Лучше рисовалки я еще не встречал. Сможете нарисовать все что душе угодно. Из минусов - это не готовая библиотека для построения графики(например диаграмм или графов, как в Вашем случае), а инструмент для рисования. Тоесть рисовать придется Вам самому ручками. Ну и въезд в неё - занятие не на 1 день. И даже не на 2.

Comment: Да, её я видел, но как раз таки нескольких дней и нету. Был бы это основной функционал - там да. А так, это нужно только для более наглядной визуализации.

Comment: Если времени нет, то d3 точно не Ваш выбор. Других, к сожалению, не могу подсказать.

Comment: Можете поискать в этом списке http://anvaka.github.io/graph-drawing-libraries/#/all

Comment: Дак я в вопросе и указал ссылку на данный ресурс - что я его нашел, но все представленные там библиотеки выстраивают дерево не так как хотелось бы. Поэтому и спросил - может кто знает другие.